# Solving the following equation by factorisation

Tags: quadratics

The given equation is,

$\frac{m}{n}x^2+\frac{n}{m}=1-2x$

What I've tried,

Multiplying the equation by $n$, we get

$mx^2+\frac{n^2}{m}x=n-2nx$

Now what? I am completely confused about what to do. Have I followed the correct steps?

Comment: group like powers of x and then complete the square

Comment: Things will look nicer if you multiply through by $mn$.

Comment: $(mx + n)^2 = mn$ is what you should get if you follow both the above suggestions. I'm sure you can take it up from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiply by $\frac{m}{n}$ on both sides, you get

$(\frac{m}{n})^2 x^2+1=(1-2x)\frac{m}{n}$

$(\frac{m}{n})^2 x^2+2x\frac{m}{n} + 1 -\frac{m}{n}=0$

$(\frac{mx}{n})^2+2(\frac{mx}{n}) + (1 -\frac{m}{n})=0$

can you see you got a quadratic equation in $\frac{mx}{n}$?

Do quadratic formula here then divide by $\frac{m}{n}$ and you got what x equals to

Comment: The title requires the equation to be solved by **factorization**.

Comment: easy. turn the quadratic equation into a factorization

Comment: I don't think that is the aim of this exercise.

Comment: You might be right. I want to know if  Abhishekstudent found what he wants, but he hasn't replied yet